# datatool and pgfmath option

Tags: datatool, pgfmath

Compiling this file

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[math=fp]{datatool}
\usepackage[math=pgfmath]{datatool}

\DTLloaddb{scores}{sample-student-records.csv} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/samples

\begin{document}

\DTLmeanforcolumn{scores}{Assignment 1}{\averagescore}%
\averagescore\%.

\end{document}
```

I get

```
... 

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
               p
l.11 ...olumn{scores}{Assignment 1}{\averagescore}
                                                  %
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...@tmpcpz 0}\let \@dtl@chopzeroesnext 
                                                  =\@dtl@gobbletonil "
l.11 ...olumn{scores}{Assignment 1}{\averagescore}
                                                  %
! Argument of \@dtl@gobbletonil has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.11 ...olumn{scores}{Assignment 1}{\averagescore}
                                                  %
Runaway argument?

...
```

but if I use the option `math=fp` everything is fine.

Comment: Looks like it is somehow related to the data you read from the csv file. So maybe you should provide us with some sample dataset from your file to make your example complete.

Answer (score 2):

The version v2.12 of the package datatool solves this problem.